# Date Picker minimum date and minute interval visual error

Tags: swift, date, uidatepicker

I have a `UIDatePicker` and set minimum date and minute interval, however there is a visual bug when selecting date. Minimum minute is selectable but appears with the non-selectable grey color.

My code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!

override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels
   datePicker.minuteInterval = 5
   datePicker.minimumDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 7200) // 7200 is equal to 2 hours
}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: What you want isn't very clear to me. If it is 08:32 right now, what do you want the earliest selectable time to be? 10:30 or 10:35? What about if it is 08:34 right now?

Comment: @Sweeper for example: if it's 12:34 right now I want 14:35 to be the minimum. If it's 12:35 I want 14:35 to be the minimum. And if it's 12:36 I want 14:40 to be the minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the date picker is somewhat confused because the minimum date isn't a multiple of five minutes. For example, if you opened the app at 12:34, then `Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 7200)` is going to be 14:34, and that doesn't correspond to any date on the date picker, which might be why it is behaving weirdly like this. I don't *think* this intended though.

Anyway, if you always give it a date that is a multiple of 5 minutes (or whatever `minuteInterval` you have), then it will work as expected.

From your description of the desired behaviour, it seems like you want to find the next five minute mark if the current minute component is not divisible by 5, then add 2 hours. You can do:

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
let now = Date()
let currentMinute = calendar.component(.minute, from: now)
let mod = currentMinute % 5
let minutesUntilNextMultipleOf5 = mod == 0 ? mod : 5 - mod
let minDate = calendar.date(byAdding:
                DateComponents(hour: 2, minute: minutesUntilNextMultipleOf5),
                to: now)
datePicker.minimumDate = minDate
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't find a solution to this. Could you please explain me the minutesUntilNextMultipleOf5 constant?

Comment: @DiegoFlores It's calculating how many minutes we need to add, until we get to the next 5 minute mark. If the current minute is already divisible by 5, then we don't need to add anything (0). Otherwise we need to add `5 - currentMinute % 5` minutes.